# Net::DNS::Resolver and auto configuration

Tags: perl, dns, perl-module

i am trying to use Net::DNS::Resolver on winodws to test some different DNS Servers .
when i use `$resolver=Net::DNS::Resolver->new ()` from perl script when i close the script change the default dns server and run the script again the $resolver points to the new DNS ,

but when i use this `my $resolver=Net::DNS::Resolver->new ()`  inside a loop and initialize it again and change the default dns server , the $resolver keep with the old configuration.   any idea how to solve this problem ?

worth to mention i am using this module on windows

Answer (score 0):

The module uses a Windows system call to get the system-wide resolver information. It's quite possible that that system call (and the Perl module wrapping it) does not expect the information to change during the lifetime of a running script.

In any case, changing the system-wide configuration just in order to query a different server is not the best way to do it. Why not simply set the nameserver in the `Net::DNS::Resolver` object directly each time through the loop? In your case, it'd be something like `$resolver->nameservers([$ns_ip_or_name]);`, which must be easier than changing the DNS settings in Windows.